Polars: Collect errors per cell value
I am doing some column transformations in polars using expression API functions.
If there are errors while performing those functions, an polars error is raised like
Failed to do ... for 4000 of 9000 columns
Is there a way to know which 4000 of those elements failed, and maybe even collect errors in a separate column?

I don't want to use row wise map functions, but could not find any other way till now.
I am trying to collect cell wise errors while applying a function over a polars expression, but could not find a way to do it without the map_ functions

Can you include some example code which produces this error?
